# Redraw a form from a timer tick handler

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have developed application in console application. I want to call mainform function inside another method. i have tried but error throws as
"Error 2 'System.Drawing.Graphics' is a 'type' but is used like a 'variable'"

```
private void MainForm_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    Render_Plot(e.Graphics, 0); 
}

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Render_Plot(Graphics, 0); //Error--how to call render_plot function here
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to solve your problem starting from incorrect point.

There is no need to call your drawing method from timer since it is already being called from `Paint` method.

So all you need - is just redraw your form from timer using `this.Invalidate` or `this.Refresh` (first one just marks form for redrawing so form will be repainted when it will be possible and second one immediately tries to redraw):

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Refresh();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't, you call `Invalidate` which will re-render it (and therefore call `Paint`)

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Invalidate()
}
```